# How can I make bash not match `.` and `..` with `.*`

Tags: bash, wildcards, dot-files

When I try to match all dot files in a directory with `.*` it seems to have a nasty side-effect: besides matching all (real) files and directories, it matches `.` and `..`.

```
bash-3.2$ mv test/.* dest/
mv: rename test/. to dest/.: Invalid argument
mv: test/.. and dest/.. are identical
```

This seems really weird, since they are basically 'fake' directories, just there to make relative paths easy.  They are not part of the contents of a directory, and I don't ever want them matched when I try to move the contents of one directory to another directory.  I can't think of any scenario where I would want them matched by `.*`.

So how can I turn this off?  (Besides using Z shell, which is not always available, and which may not be the shell in use by someone running a function I've written.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `GLOBIGNORE` bash variable.

```
       GLOBIGNORE
              A colon-separated list of patterns defining the set of filenames
              to be ignored by pathname expansion.  If a filename matched by a
              pathname  expansion  pattern also matches one of the patterns in
              GLOBIGNORE, it is removed from the list of matches.
```

and

```
       .......................-.  The file names ``.''  and ``..''  are always
       ignored  when GLOBIGNORE is set and not null.
```

So if you set

```
GLOBIGNORE='*/.:*/..'
```

then `path/.*` will not match `.` and `..`, as you ask.

Comment: Wouldn't `GLOBIGNORE=.:..` more succinctly accomplish the same thing?  Or is there a subtle difference I'm missing?

Answer (score -1):

A glob pattern would be `.[^.]*` -- it matches something with at least 2 characters where the 2nd char is not a dot.

Documentation for filename pattern matching is in the bash man page or here: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching

---

Jonathan Callen raises a good point. You can use a fairly simple extended pattern

```
shopt -s extglob
ls -d .!(.|)
```

Comment: That will miss files named like `..install.cmd` (A real file I've seen in the wild).